# Inserting a row at a location based on value/formulas from another row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I feel this may be a several part question - so at this stage, I'm more asking if I can do this and what direction you think I should take that would work best.

I'm trying to build a timesheet program (see attached image), where you click a button to insert a new line in consecutive order down the page (the script that I have so far is attached below).

Example of my timesheet so far;
[image]

I have a script already that inserts a row based on values/formulas in the last active row and inserts it into the next row, however, it picks up all the previous row data, where as I need just formulas, lists, formatting etc, not the data (as staff forget to delete out the data). How can I change it so that it picks up all the particulars (pre-determined stuff like formatting, formulas etc) from a certain row (row 8) and inserts that row into the next active row?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Comment: I've tried your script and I think the reason you are getting the data when adding a new row is because your script also copies the formula from the previous row. It is expected for the new row to have the same data from the previous row since they now have the same formula. 
If you want to copy only the row format, you can use `formatOnly = true` parameter instead of `contentsOnly=false`

Comment: Hmm, bugger - yep your idea works well except I have formulas in columns B, C and E that I need to bring down as well.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet so that I can replicate your issue and try to solve it on my side? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in [`range.copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#advanced-parameters_1) to copy everything except the values.

Instead, you could first copy the format and then copy the formulas.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  var rangeTo = sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol);
  range.copyTo(rangeTo, {formatOnly: true});

  var formulas = range.getFormulasR1C1();
  rangeTo.setFormulasR1C1(formulas);
}
```

Reference:

- [getFormulasR1C1()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1)
- [setFormulasR1C1(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasr1c1formulas)